# IIS Redirects - Redirecting domain without website binding

Tags: redirect, iis

I have a bunch of domains (50+), e.g. example1.org example2.org, example3.org that I would like to redirect (301) to a single domain, examplethebest.org. Nothing is hosted on any of these domains other than examplethebest.

I've set up all the example domains in the registrar's DNS to point to the IP of my web server.

I was wondering if redirecting these is something I could achieve via rewrites in the applicationHost.config file. Or do I need to add bindings for example1 - example3.org in examplethebest's website bindings?

Just wanted to add that I understand how to do the rewrites via the web.config in examplethebest if I add bindings for the domains I want to redirect, but would rather not have loads of domain bindings - e.g. what is best practice here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the issue I had on this particular web server was that the default website (listening to all requests on port 80) was stopped - the other websites all had specific bindings.

At least two possible solutions for this one:

1. Starting the default website and adding {http_host} rewrites in there
2. Creating another website, make it listen to all requests on port 80 with just a web.config and putting the {http_host} rewrites in there.

We went with option 2.